# Menu Missing in Epicor but available in Database

Tags: epicorerp, epicor, epicor10

I am working with Epicor 10.0.700.4. I could not see few menu items in my Epicor screen, but those menus are available in back-end Database. Is there a way to figure out the inactive menus or the hidden menus in EPICOR or from DB tables. I checked the DoNotDisplayInMenu column in Database, but the menu's i'm searching in Epicor is True in DB.

Please help. Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: For anyone who sees this in the future. Please refrain from manually updating the Epicor database. This can result in voiding of your warranty. There are also specific licensing configurations that you need to abide by

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can query the Ice.Menu table to see all menu objects in the system (via SQL or BAQ). The following criteria will identify screens which you do not see as a security manager but do exist in the system:

1. Ice.Menu "Enabled" is false
2. Ice.Menu "DoNotDisplayInMenu" is true
3. Ice.Menu "Company" is a company to which the user does not have access
4. Ice.Security bound to the menu specifies a company to which the user does not have access
5. Ice.Security bound to the menu specifies a NoEntryList that either contains the user or a security group that contains the user.
6. The menu item requires a module is not licensed.

Answer (score 0):

The menu may also be hidden because the current user is not set to see it. Check the security settings for the menu item.

Comment: I am the admin with full access to all menus. Do we have an option via DB?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the Menu table lists down all the Menu Items in Epicor standard irrespective of Licensing.
And currently, there's no flag for the "Licensed" in the Menu table.